# Curl, Redirection not loading actual webpage

Tags: php, redirect, curl, cloudflare

There has to be some form of redirect that is happening through java.

If you load this webpage https://btc-e.com/index.php

you will not actually get the webpage if you use curl. you get just a bunch of java. How do i go about getting to the actual HTML so i can start a login process.

I know this website provides an API, but i need a `CURL` `login` method, that uses the website and not the API.

here is all the code which i am using

```
<?php


$curl = new Curl();
$curl->setSsl();

$curl->setCookieFile('whatever_cookie_file.cook');

$page = $curl->get("https://btc-e.com/index.php");
echo $page;

class Curl {

public $curl;
public $manual_follow;
public $redirect_url;
public $cookiefile = null;
public $headers = array();

function Curl($proxy=false) {
    $this->curl = curl_init();
    $this->headers[] = "Accept: */*;q=0.5, text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript";
    $this->headers[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
    $this->headers[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
    $this->headers[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
    $this->headers[] = "Accept-Charset: utf-8;ISO-8859-1;iso-8859-2;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
    $this->headers[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
    $this->headers[] = "Pragma: "; // browsers keep this blank.


    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-GB; rv:1.9.0.14) Gecko/2009082707 Firefox/3.0.14 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)');
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);

    if($proxy != false){
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_PROXY,$proxy);
    }// end if proxy != false

    if (ini_get('open_basedir') == '' && ini_get('safe_mode' == 'Off')){
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    } else {
        $this->manual_follow = true;
    }

    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

    $this->setRedirect();
}

function addHeader($header){
    $this->headers[] = $header;
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers);
}

function header($val){
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, $val);
}

function noAjax(){
    foreach($this->headers as $key => $val){
        if ($val == "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest"){
            unset($this->headers[$key]);
        }
    }
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers);
}

function setAjax(){
    $this->headers[] = "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest";
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers);
}

function setSsl($username = null, $password = null){
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    if ($username && $password){
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
    }
}

function setBasicAuth($username,$password){
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
}


function setCookieFile($file){
    if (file_exists($file)) {

    } else {
        $handle = fopen($file, 'w+') or print('The cookie file could not be opened. Make sure this directory has the correct permissions');
        fclose($handle);
    }
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $file);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $file);
    $this->cookiefile = $file;
}

function getCookies(){
      $contents = file_get_contents($this->cookiefile);
      $cookies = array();
      if ($contents){
        $lines = explode("\n",$contents);
        if (count($lines)){
              foreach($lines as $key=>$val){
                $tmp = explode("\t",$val);
                if (count($tmp)>3){
                      $tmp[count($tmp)-1] = str_replace("\n","",$tmp[count($tmp)-1]);
                      $tmp[count($tmp)-1] = str_replace("\r","",$tmp[count($tmp)-1]);
                      $cookies[$tmp[count($tmp)-2]]=$tmp[count($tmp)-1];
                }
              }
        }
      }
      return $cookies;
}

function setDataMode($val){
     curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, $val);
}

function close() {
      curl_close($this->curl);
}

function getInfo(){
      return curl_getinfo($this->curl);
}

function getInstance() {
    static $instance;
    if (!isset($instance)) {
        $curl = new Curl;
        $instance = array($curl);
    }
    return $instance[0];
}

function setTimeout($connect, $transfer) {
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $connect);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $transfer);
}

function getError() {
    return curl_errno($this->curl) ? curl_error($this->curl) : false;
}

function disableRedirect() {
    $this->setRedirect(false);
}

function setRedirect($enable = true) {
    if ($enable) {
        $this->manual_follow = !curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    } else {
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
        $this->manual_follow = false;
    }
}

function getHttpCode() {
    return curl_getinfo($this->curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
}


function makeQuery($data) {
    if (is_array($data)) {
        $fields = array();
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
             $fields[] = $key . '=' . urlencode($value);
        }
        $fields = implode('&', $fields);
    } else {
        $fields = $data;
    }

    return $fields;
}

// FOLLOWLOCATION manually if we need to
function maybeFollow($page) {
    if (strpos($page, "\r\n\r\n") !== false) {
        list($headers, $page) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $page, 2);
    }

    $code = $this->getHttpCode();

    if ($code > 300 && $code < 310) {
        $info = $this->getInfo();

        preg_match("#Location: ?(.*)#i", $headers, $match);
        $this->redirect_url = trim($match[1]);

        if (substr_count($this->redirect_url,"http://") == 0 && isset($info['url']) && substr_count($info['url'],"http://")){
            $url_parts = parse_url($info['url']);
            if (isset($url_parts['host']) && $url_parts['host']){
                $this->redirect_url = "http://".$url_parts['host'].$this->redirect_url;
            }
        }

        if ($this->manual_follow) {
            return $this->get($this->redirect_url);
        }
    } else {
        $this->redirect_url = '';
    }

    return $page;
}


function plainPost($url,$data){
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    $page = curl_exec($this->curl);

    $error = curl_errno($this->curl);
    if ($error != CURLE_OK || empty($page)) {
        return false;
    }

    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '');

    return $this->maybeFollow($page);
}

function post($url, $data) {
    $fields = $this->makeQuery($data);
    //var_dump($fields);

    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    $page = curl_exec($this->curl);

    $error = curl_errno($this->curl);
    if ($error != CURLE_OK || empty($page)) {
        return false;
    }

    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '');

    return $this->maybeFollow($page);
}

function get($url, $data = null) {

    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, false);
    if (!is_null($data)) {
        $fields = $this->makeQuery($data);
        $url .= '?' . $fields;
    }

    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $page = curl_exec($this->curl);

    $error = curl_errno($this->curl);

    if ($error != CURLE_OK || empty($page)) {
        return false;
    }

    return $this->maybeFollow($page);
}
}



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question was not specifically with curl.

Due to very simple cookie verification of the website this is why i was unable to load the initial webpage.

To solve this problem simply parse out all needed values from the initially loaded webpage.

Once you have all needed values just simply write a cookie with everything included. After The cookie is passed to server you are now allowed to see the content of the webpage.

To solve this problem further and to do more advanced java script manipulation a system such as phantomjs with casperjs and or using a solution such as Selenium with PHP_unit headless mode.

Hope this helps anyone who faced the same problem